# How to handle a POST request in C#

Tags: c#, .net, http, post

I'm writing a .NET-based application that communicates a server running a server script also written in .NET, and I want the client to send some data over HTTP POST that the server then handles.

My code already sends the post request:

```cs
await httpClient.PostAsync(serverIP, content); //Line of code for example purposes
```

What I'm stuck on is the second half: processing the data on the server side.

How would I go about doing this?

PS: I am still very new with HTTP and web-based coding in general

Comment: I've two questions, 
1) Is your content object includes JSON or a string?
2) I understand you're using .net on the server side but is it a Web API, MVC controller or an old school web form?

Comment: I' pretty sure the two overloads for PostAsync are Uri and content. In your web api controller make sure the route you define matches the Uri and the controller method takes an object that matches the shape you are passing. There are heaps of tutorials for this that can be found with a google search. Posting and building APIs are arguable the most fundamental concepts of .net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the post request with a Generic Handler (.ashx) file. Add a generic handler file to your server application. In Generic Handler you can handle the post request as below

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
{ 
    //Detect Http Method
    if(context.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
    {
        //Get the posted values
        int val1 = context.Request["key1"];
        int val2 = context.Request["key2"];

        //... your logic

        //send the response back with http status code
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: .ashx files seem to be linked to ASP.NET, so do I need to somehow implement that into my application? (I have never used ASP.NET, and I'm just now learning about .ashx files)

Comment: You are right. .ashx files are served under ASP.NET applications. To use a generic web handler you can host it under an ASP.NET web application served by IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
 var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, byteArrayContent);

 var readResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

 // Your code goes here
```